# JOGL-2.0 NSAutoreleaseNoPool Error

Tags: opengl, jogl, nsautoreleasepool

I switched from JOGL 1.1 to JOGL 2, and for some reason, I'm getting strange errors.

I've isolated the problem to creating the GLCanvas.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.getDefault()));
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get this weird error.

```
2012-07-26 16:50:23.688 java[903:1303] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10014cf00 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2012-07-26 16:50:23.690 java[903:1303] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1001512b0 of class NSConcreteValue autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2012-07-26 16:50:23.690 java[903:1303] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100123e50 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2012-07-26 16:50:23.690 java[903:1303] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100151310 of class NSConcreteValue autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2012-07-26 16:50:23.690 java[903:1303] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100151340 of class NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2012-07-26 16:50:24.170 java[903:1303] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10204a690 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2012-07-26 16:50:24.171 java[903:1303] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x102056390 of class NSConcreteValue autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2012-07-26 16:50:24.171 java[903:1303] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100123e50 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2012-07-26 16:50:24.171 java[903:1303] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x102055c70 of class NSConcreteValue autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2012-07-26 16:50:24.171 java[903:1303] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10206b4a0 of class NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

I've seen another person have a similar problem, but nowhere did I reference swt.jar

A little more background:

I'm using eclipse, imported jogl.all.jar and gluegen-rt.jar and set their natives to the macosx folder.

The program runs fine, but it's just really annoying to see these errors pop up every time I'm running it.

This was from a fresh copy of the jogamp-all-plaforms from the website.

Anyone have any ideas how this error can be fixed?

I'm running Snow Leopard 10.6.8

Comment: Hi Eugene, have you tried one of the [last builds](http://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/master/gluegen_876-joal_603-jogl_1414-jocl_1066/archive/)?